# Python listbox expand and hide after clicks

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have the following sample code below. Is there a way to expand the listbox, showing 10 out of 100 numbers when clicked? And when selecting one of the numbers, does the listbox hide the others again?

```css
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

for i in range(100):
    listbox.insert(END, i)

# attach listbox to scrollbar
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, height = 1)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect an event handler to the `<Button-1>` signal, and toggle the listbox height every time:

```
def listbox_clicked(event):
    listbox = event.widget
    if listbox['height'] == 1:
        listbox.config(height=10)
    else:
        listbox.config(height=1)

listbox.bind('<Button-1>', listbox_clicked)
```

Comment: This is a better answer than my post, but you'll need to include both to make it work well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe packing options will help.

```
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, expand=True)
listbox.pack(fill=Y, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for the help, but all I needed was a combobox!